# Mocking a function which is called from another file in typescript tests with jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

I have a function `processCosts` in `prepareStatement.ts`. `processCosts` calls a  function, `calculatePrice` imported from `coreLogic.ts`.

I have a test file `reports.integration.ts` which imports `processCosts` but I want to mock `calculatePrice`, which is the function `processCosts` calls. I created a file `coreLogic.ts` under my `__mocks__` folder with the content:

```
export const calculatePrice = jest.fn(() => {});
```

and then in my test file, outside my test's `it(...)`, but inside the `describe(...)` I wrote

```
jest.mock('../statements/prepareStatement');
```

Finally, the test itself:

```
it('should calculate processCost and 4 x what calculatePrice returns', async () => {
    (calculatePrice as jest.Mock).mockImplementationOnce(() => 100.00);
    expect(processCost).to.equal(400.00); // processCost will do 4*whatever calculatePrice is
}
```

When I run my code I get

```
TypeError: coreLogic_1.calculatePrice.mockImplementationOnce is not a function
```

Can someone point out where I've gone wrong? The people who have done something similar to what I have done are calling the method they mock in their test as opposed to inside another imported function. Regardless, after attaching a debugger, my code baulks on this line:

```
(calculatePrice as jest.Mock).mockImplementationOnce(() => 100.00);
```

Comment: How does prepareStatement relate to coreLogic? Please give a [mre]. Also note that if your jest.mock isn't at the top level of the file, it won't get hoisted so the imports in the test and real code will likely get the original version.

Comment: this is what fixed it. i moved the `jest.mock(...)` outside the `describe(...)` and `it(...)` to the top level of the file and everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

this is what fixed it. I moved the jest.mock(...) outside the describe(...) and it(...) to the top level of the file and everything started working.